# Android studioのAVD Managerについて

Tags: android

Android studio初心者です。
Android studioのインストールが終わりプロジェクトを開いたところまではいいのですが、AVD Managerがどこにも見当たりません。
toolsメニュー→Android→AVD managerという手順であるらしいのですが、toolsメニューを開いてもAndroidの文字が見当たりません。
どうすればいいのでしょうか？回答お願いします。
バージョンAndroid studio3.0

Comment: エラー文に従ってbuildtoolというものをインストールしたら出来るようになりました！ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio 3.0 から面倒になりました。2.x まではいつでも Tools メニューに表示されていたと思うのですが。。。

さて、改めて Android Studio 3.0 をインストールし新規プロジェクトを作成してみましたが、やはり表示されません。
調べてみると下記にて AVD Manager を表示する方法が回答されていました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46948322/how-to-open-avd-manager-in-android-studio-3-0-version/47143861#47143861

要は**プロジェクトのビルドに成功すれば表示される**、という事だと思います。

先ほど作成した新規プロジェクトも、初期は EventLog にエラーが出力されていましたが、エラーの原因を解消後は Tools に Android メニューアイテムが表示されるようになりました。

是非試してみてください。